# How do I show a vector icon in my ToolbarAndroid from react-native-vector-icons (react native)

Tags: react-native

This is my simple react native page:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    ToolbarAndroid
} from 'react-native';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';


class myapp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ToolbarAndroid
                title="AwesomeApp"
                navIconName="md-arrow-back"
                actions={[
                    {
                        title: 'Settings',
                        iconName: 'md-cog',
                        show: 'always'
                    }
                ]}
                style={styles.toolbar}
            />
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar: {
        backgroundColor: '#e9eaed',
        height: 56
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```

I don't get anyicons...

cannot find any simple enough examples to understand how to use icons

I tried also

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid ...
```

I get this error:

> RNVectorIconsModule not available, did you properly integrate the
>   module?

Comment: How did you link the module ? rnpm link ? or manually ?

Comment: @agent_hunt: yeah, I missed the extra step to add to the gradle files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @agent_hunt pointed out in the comment, made me realize I didn't follow ALL the install instructions... I needed to add some settings to my android cradle files specifically for the toolbar support.

now it works